# How can I remove the line "TODO add your handling code here" in Netbeans when I add a new event for Swing component?

Tags: swing, netbeans

When I add a new event for a component on a Swing form, the IDE puts the line "**TODO add your handling code here**".
How can I change that default lest the IDE comment?

Comment: Just erase it using the editor

Comment: I wish I could justify voting you up SOLELY on the basis of having the album cover of the best album ever made as your Gravatar.  Unfortunately, the question is a bit incomplete.  Are you trying to figure out how to make the IDE not put that there by default, or is there something else to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer in relation to Metallica. And, yes, I want Netbeans to print a blank line instead of this comment by default.

Answer (score 4):

This is done via templates in Netbeans. Start by clicking on the Tools menu > Templates. Then in the Tree that shows up you can navigate to the appropriate template. Select the template that you wish to change, then click "Open in Editor". Make your changes and save.

Next time that you insert code Netbeans will use your modified template.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But could you point me to the right template which I have to change? 'Cause I looked for one that contains this comment and didn't find any.